# Can't conditionally add script to Azure Devops Yaml pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-devops-hosted-agent, azure-devops-pipelines

I'm trying to make use of Container Job template in a pipeline which runs on both Microsoft Hosted and Self-Hosted (Containerized) build agents.

ContainerJob template works well when run in `Microsoft Hosted` but fails in Self-Hosted agent saying `cannot run container inside a containerized build agent`. Error makes sense though.

I figured that if below section can be added/removed conditionally then same Container Job template works in both agents.

```
${{ if not(parameters.isSelfHosted) }}:
  container:
    image: ${{ parameters.generalImage}}
    endpoint: ${{ parameters.endpoint}} 
  environment: ${{ parameters.environment }}
```

But the condition is always true and `container` section is added always and failed in self-hosted agent always. I think expressions are not allowed randomly inside a template.

I can separate out this template into 2 templates and load them in respective build agent but that's the last resort. Any help in dynamically creating/altering a template is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for conditional container job? See my script:

```
parameters:
- name: isSelfHosted
  displayName: isSelfHosted
  type: boolean
  default: true
  values:
  - false
  - true

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    ${{ if not(parameters.isSelfHosted) }}:
      container: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2
      steps:
        - task: CmdLine@2
          inputs:
            script: |
                echo 2.2 SDK

    ${{ if eq(parameters.isSelfHosted, 'true') }}:
      container: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1
      steps:
        - task: CmdLine@2
          inputs:
            script: |
                echo 2.1 SDK
```

I can choose which container (.net core 2.1 or .net core 2.2) via the value of `isSelfHosted` parameter.

It uses [Runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script#use-parameters-in-pipelines), so I can manage the condition(check or uncheck the box) when running the pipeline:

[image]

**Update:**

See [Job, stage, and step templates with parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#job-stage-and-step-templates-with-parameters)

Move the content below into a template file:

```
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    ${{ if not(parameters.isSelfHosted) }}:
      container: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2
      steps:
        - task: CmdLine@2
          inputs:
            script: |
                echo 2.2 SDK

    ${{ if eq(parameters.isSelfHosted, 'true') }}:
      container: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1
      steps:
        - task: CmdLine@2
          inputs:
            script: |
                echo 2.1 SDK
```

Then the main `azure-pipelines.yml` should be

```
parameters:
- name: isSelfHosted
  displayName: isSelfHosted
  type: boolean
  default: true
  values:
  - false
  - true

stages:
- template: templates/xxx.yml  # Template reference
  parameters:
    isSelfHosted: xxx (Value of isSelfHosted parameter)
```

Comment: Thanks. But i'm trying to use it in  `template`. So i will be passing the parameter into the template and put the condition inside the template.

Comment: Thanks. But the the problem is accessing it inside the `xxx.yml` template and adding `container` script based on that condition.  The snippet i provided in my question should be in `xxx.yml` and should be adding only when `isSelfHosted` is false.